# Naudio: Encode in BackgroundWorker -> Empty target file created, Application is shut down and no exception is thrown

Tags: c#, wpf, encoding, backgroundworker, naudio

I´m having a problem with the MediaFoundationEncoder. When I execute the following code in a BackgroundWorkers DoWork method, I get an empty mp4 file, no exception is thrown and the Application is shut down immediately:

```
private void Mp4_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(_currentFilePath))
        {
            using (var encoder = new MediaFoundationEncoder(quality))
            {
                encoder.Encode(_mp4Path, reader);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.LogError("...", ex, true, false);
    }
}
```

All file paths are valid and the _currentFilePath variable points to a wav file of about 50 MBs that is not being used and that I can successfully encode when above code is not run in a BackgroundWorker. Also the RunWorkerCompleted method is not called. When Debugging, I get to `encoder.Encode(_mp4Path, reader);` and that´s it. Any ideas?

Comment: This is likely caused by an unmanaged exception in the third party code, which causes the application to be terminated abruptly. Have a look in Event Viewer under Windows Logs / Application - there might be something in there about the crash.

Comment: @Mathew Watson: Hi and thanks for answering. I had a look and found no events related to the shutdown... Maybe you have another idea? :-)

Comment: @Matthew Watson : I wouldn't call it an unmanged exception..  It is an exception that is caught in the third party code but not reported.  If it wasn't handled in the third party code then an exception message would of been reported.

Comment: @jdweng I meant an application error, like buffer overrun or illegal memory access. I assume the third party code isn't handling it because the application is being terminated with no error message. If it was being handled, the application wouldn't be terminating.

Comment: It could be capturing the exception and then just returning without any error messages.

Comment: @jdweng But then the application wouldn't be terminated?

Comment: No.  The c++ would simply return to the c# code.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry I wasn't clear: What I meant was: The OP has said that the application terminates suddenly, so therefore the C++ isn't simply returning to the C# code because if it did so, the application wouldn't suddenly terminate.

Comment: @Matthew Watson : I think you are wrong.  I believe the c++ is returning to c#.  It must.  The Managed code wraps the unmanaged code so any exception will return to c#.  All the OPs say is the application is shutting down.  In c++ is the application was handled you would never get to the exception handler in c#.  So the code would simply return from Mp4_DoWork.  We do have the code that calls Mp4_DoWork so we cannot tell why the code is shutting down.

Comment: Hello again and thanks for the comments! It was another issue in the end as I hadn´t seen that Application.Current.Shutdown was beeing called in another Thread. My bad and thanks a lot for trying to help! I was having several issues with this code, as the MediaFoundationEncoder takes a com object that throws an exception when beeing used in the background thread, but that´s another story :-)